# Is the Station-to-Station protocol secure?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman

After I've read a lot about key exchange many sources state that the [Station-to-Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol) is secure, since it also verifies the entity on the other side.

Well how is that true, if an active *Man in the Middle* can just send it's own public key and sign the concatenated shared `x` and `y` with it's own private key?

Wouldn't it be as secure as classic [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important premise of STS is that Alice and Bob already know each other's public keys. Possibly, this "knowledge" is acquired through certificates, as part of a [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure). See the relevant quote from the [Wikipedia page on STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol):

> Public key certificates may be sent in steps 2 and 3 if the keys are not known in advance.

The [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) protocol, when used with the "DHE" cipher suites and with certificate-based client authentication, is actually an incarnation of STS.

Comment: Well then how exactly is it a key exchange protocol if both parties already have a secure means of communication - they know each other's public keys. They already have shared information which is secret because it is associated with the corresponding private keys.

Comment: They know each other _signature_ public keys. A public key is not necessarily fit for asymmetric encryption. Moreover, using a new DH key pair on-the-fly grants forward secrecy.

Comment: What exactly should `signature public key` mean? How is it different?

Comment: "Signature public key" = "public key fit for use in a signature algorithm". E.g. DSA, ECDSA... such public keys do not necessarily support asymmetric encryption or key exchange. It so happens that the most used asymmetric encryption algorithm (RSA) and the most used signature algorithm (RSA) share the same kind of key, allowing a "RSA key" to be used for both usages (although you do not necessarily want to), but that's not the general case for all algorithms cryptographers have come up with.